# Deleting a user from Call manager (CUCM)

Tags: ldap

I have tried to delete a user from the named server but the response is this **"NOTE: The add and delete function are disabled because the user directory is sync with LDAP"**. What should I do.

Comment: Delete the user from the linked LDAP (often Active Directory) location.

Comment: But I already did that.

Comment: Hmmm. If the user is already gone from LDAP, they shouldn't appear in CUCM. Maybe CUCM is slow to get updated?

Comment: Apparently, the sync between LDAP and CUCM had been set to 24hrs and that is why the system took long to delete that user. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's good to hear. I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the user from the linked LDAP (often Active Directory) location.
2. Wait for CUCM to sync with LDAP.